# XCode 3 -> XCode 4  = No Files

Tags: xcode3to4

> I have got a small App, developed with
>   XCode 3, in the App Store. Now I want
>   to update some features!  In the
>   meantime I have updated to XCode 4.2.
>   It works fine with new projetcs.  But:
>   When ever I will open my XCode 3
>   Project, nothing happens. The project
>   navigator says:"No files"!
>
> Can you help me!
>
> [This is the link to my Child's Age
>   project. (zip-file) ][1]
>
> [1]:
>   http://files.me.com/rafta2009/h7qkfz

Comment: Is there anything in your search bar below the navigator?

Comment: Is there a compelling reason why you need to use Xcode 4 ? It's still pretty immature compared to Xcode 3 (personally I find it pretty much unusable) so unless you absolutely have to "upgrade" then it might be better to wait until it's more stable.

Answer (score 0):

Original Poster has reported that this was the solution to their problem:

> Create new Workspace and add your XCode3 App-Folder to the workspace.